# Google apis not available in android sdk manager

Tags: android, adt, android-sdk-tools

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have ADT v22.6.2. I am not able to see any of the Google apis in the sdk manager.
[image]

I wanted to get the licensing package. Normally sdk manager looks like following:
[image]

Following is my `.android/androidtools.cfg` file:

```
### Settings for Android Tool
#Sat Jun 28 18:24:02 IST 2014
http.proxyPort=
sdkman.enable.previews=false
http.proxyHost=
sdkman.ask.adb.restart=false
sdkman.use.dl.cache=false
sdkman.force.http=false
```

Following are the official addon sites:
[image]

I have tried adding following User defined sites but no success:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to the latest SDK Tools, etc. in the Tools section of the SDK Manager. Restart the SDK Manager after that, and additional options, including the ones that you are missing, should appear.